# Openlayers - Can't change renderer to DOM

Tags: openlayers-3

No matter what I try I can't seem to stop it from using Canvas. I want all the tile images to be added to the DOM not canvas - http://jsfiddle.net/xug1nsbb/

```
renderer: "dom",
```

This really old version on OL is working how I want http://greatgasbeetle.com/PenistoneRoadZoomify/#zoom=5&lat=73002&lon=13777&layers=B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `renderer` option belongs to `ol.Map`, not `ol.View`.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xug1nsbb/3/ but now nothing displays..?

Comment: Set width and height of your div.